# Create aws_db_subnet_group with terraform throw Error creating DB Subnet Group: InvalidParameterValue

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm using terraform to create an RDS instance, to do so I need to have an **aws_db_subnet_group** resource. I can create the RDS using an aws_db_subnet_group created by the Amazon website but when I try to create the aws_db_subnet_group from terraform script I receive the error InvalidParameterValue.

This is the terraform script:

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "default" {
  name        = "cse-cr"
  description = "Private subnets for RDS instance"
  subnet_ids  = ["subnet-0c8764fcb28b04c8c", "subnet-0ca53ff9b621e2c89"]
}
```

and this is the error:

```
 Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_db_subnet_group.default: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_db_subnet_group.default: Error creating DB Subnet Group: InvalidParameterValue: Some input subnets in :[subnet-0ca53ff9b621e2c89, subnet-0c8764fcb28b04c8c] are invalid.
        status code: 400, request id: 66166ec8-9b79-41d3-bdf7-a5cdb66f5f95

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
```

I have seen multiple example on internet and the only difference I can see is that I'm using 2 preexisting subnet created from someone else and not from my Terraform script.

result of the command:

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets --subnet-ids subnet-0ca53ff9b621e2c89 subnet-0c8764fcb28b04c8c

{
    "Subnets": [
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
            "AvailableIpAddressCount": 250,
            "CidrBlock": "10.112.173.0/24",
            "DefaultForAz": false,
            "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
            "State": "available",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-0ca53ff9b621e2c89",
            "VpcId": "vpc-0ec46ccebc8108670",
            "AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation": false,
            "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
            "Tags": [

            ]
        },
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1b",
            "AvailableIpAddressCount": 251,
            "CidrBlock": "10.112.174.0/24",
            "DefaultForAz": false,
            "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
            "State": "available",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-0c8764fcb28b04c8c",
            "VpcId": "vpc-0ec46ccebc8108670",
            "AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation": false,
            "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
            "Tags": [

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the output from describing the subnets? Something like `aws ec2 describe-subnets --subnet-ids subnet-0ca53ff9b621e2c89 subnet-0c8764fcb28b04c8c` would be useful.

Comment: Thanks I have just added the info in the post, but I can create an aws_db_subnet_group with the same VPC and subnet from the amazon website

Comment: Hmmm... I can't see anything wrong with that. The subnets need to be across at least 2 different AZs and be in the same VPC but that should be it. The response you're seeing isn't anything to do with Terraform directly and is just the response from the AWS API telling you that you can't do that. You should be able to reproduce the same error by running `aws rds create-db-subnet-group --db-subnet-group-name cse-cr --db-subnet-group-description "Private subnets for RDS instance" -- subnet ids subnet-0ca53ff9b621e2c89 subnet-0c8764fcb28b04c8c`

Comment: I think is related to terraform because I'm able to create the db-subnet-group with the command you gave me.

Comment: And Terraform is still erroring for you? Because that error is definitely not coming from Terraform but instead AWS' API.

Comment: @carlitos081 - I assume you're able to create other AWS resources using your same TF structure? i.e. your provider and credentials, etc. are all working?

Comment: Yes, I can create everything else: ec2, rds, security_group, null_resource, etc.. all except  subnet-group

Comment: Got into the same error. I have enabled debug and found that terraform' credentials resolution is faulty. I had one credential in ~/.aws/credentials and one from aws sso login. Both were pointing to 2 different federated account. The terraform was using the correct one but my aws cli was showing the wrong one.  But eventually it gave the error. Basically my state file was being fetched and created from the dev aws account, but I was wanting my rds account to be created in staging.

Comment: In my case, the reason of this error was the fact that I forgot to set the right region value of the provider resource.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the aws_vpc data source first like this:

```
data "aws_subnet" "subnet1" {
  id = "subnet-0c8764fcb28b04c8c"
}

data "aws_subnet" "subnet2" {
  id = "subnet-0ca53ff9b621e2c89"
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "default" {
  name        = "cse-cr"
  description = "Private subnets for RDS instance"
  subnet_ids  = [data.aws_subnet.subnet1.id, data.aws_subnet.subnet2.id]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check what region you have your terraform defaulting to, as it might be erroring if the code is executing against the wrong region.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure all your resources are using the same provider in the region, the subnets should belong to that region

```html
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-2"
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "default" {
    name        = "cse-cr"
    description = "Private subnets for RDS instance"
    provider    = aws
    subnet_ids  = ["subnet-0c8764fcb28b04c8c", "subnet-0ca53ff9b621e2c89"]
}
```